# Noun form of "aver"?

Tags: etymology, language-evolution, variants

It is common in legal writing to *aver*, meaning to *allege, assert, or affirm a fact*.  (Latin root is *adver*.)

But I can't find any evidence that the obvious noun form of the word, *aversion*, has ever been used as such.  Instead, *aversion* has always and only been the noun form of *avert*, derivative of the Latin root *avers* (meaning something like *to turn away*).

I.e., it seems like the *avert* verb root **blocked** the noun form *aversion* from being used with the *aver* verb.  Is this correct?  If so, is there a term for this sort of conflict and deconfliction in English (or in linguistics more generally)?

Answer (score 25):

The [noun form](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/averment) is

> ***averment***
>
> - (Law) A formal statement by a party in a case of a fact or circumstance which the party offers to prove or substantiate.

(ODO)

[Origin](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/averment) of averment:

> 1400–50; late Middle English averrement < Middle French. See *aver, -ment*.

***[-ment](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ment#etymonline_v_32036)*** suffix usage origin:

> suffix forming nouns, originally from French and representing Latin -mentum, which was added to verb stems sometimes to represent the result or product of the action.

Comment: Is it etymologically obvious why *-ment* is the appropriate noun form, and not *-ion*?

Comment: @feetwet - the term, together with the suffix,  is from French.

Comment: @feetwet: *Aver* doesn’t fit in any of the patterns of other words that form nouns with *-ion*.  E.g. the closest comparisons one might think of, *conversion*, *aversion*, and *reversion*, come from *convert*, *avert*, *revert* respectively, and *aver* doesn’t end analogously to these.  Digging back, this is there’s a range of Latin root verbs that form *-tion* and *-sion* nouns, and *aver* doesn’t come from one of these roots (although it does come from Old French/Latin).

Answer (score 20):

There are two noun forms. The everyday one is *[averral](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/averral)*, meaning an act of averring; but there is also *[averment](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/averment)*, which has more of a legalistic flavour, as described in user240918's answer.

**Edited to add:** It seems from the comments that I am wrong about `averral`, at least as far as all the dictionaries in the world are concerned. I shall just have to stop using it, I suppose.

By the way, *aversion* is by no means the obvious noun form of *aver*. For example, from *infer* we get *inference*; from *deter* we get *deterrence*; from *confer* we get *conferral* or *conferment*. If you tried to use *infersion*, *detersion* or *confersion*, nobody would even know what you were trying to say!

Comment: *averral* is non-standard.

Comment: @Kris: For me, it's `averment` that's non-standard. But I must admit that [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=averment%2Caverral&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caverment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caverral%3B%2Cc0) agrees with you!

Comment: *Averral* appears to be a rare term, and unlike  *averment*,  is not present in  more common dictionaries. https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=OsfuW6nwE4K8kwXE5bu4CQ&ins=false&q=averral++meaning&oq=averral++meaning&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..0i7i30i19j0i19l4.101266.104547..104811...1.0..0.234.817.7j0j1......0....1.........0i7i30j0i13j0i7i10i30.czvb2nRzLZ4

Comment: @TonyK - [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/averment) and [Oxford Dictionaries online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/averment) disagree. Both have *averment*, neither has *averral* (the latter redirects [this](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/averral), though, so they're aware of it).

Comment: Doh! And [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=averral%2Caverment&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caverral%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caverment%3B%2Cc0) does as well. Not that *either* term is really popular. :-)

Comment: TonyK Possibly it's a dialect thing—I had the same gut reaction to *averral* vs *averment*. It's also possible that *averral* just sounds "more right" to me because of its similarity to *avowal*, which means about the same thing and is quite a bit more common than either *aver-* term.

Comment: Following your first two analogs: I'm now wondering why *averence* (or *averrence*) has not appeared as the noun form!

Comment: @1006a Or indeed _referral_, since _aver_ and _refer_ are quite close rhymes.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I thought about that, and it's certainly a logical parallel (at least at first glance; I don't know about the Latin roots). I just have the sense of having actually used/heard *averral* more often, probably in law school or other legal settings, but the corpora and my legal dictionaries don't bear that out and I think I'd be more likely to conflate *avowal* and *averral* since they're more semantically similar. FWIW, I don't get any "tingle of familiarity" for *averence* ;-).

Comment: "from confer we get conferral or conferment" Or "conference".

Comment: The suffix depends more on the source language and such, rather than on conformity with similar other words.  Also, sometimes multiple suffixes exist with different usages.